# Install vagrant in subdirectory

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'd like to have all of my installation scripts somewhere other than the home directory.

Right now, I have the following directory structure:

- Home

  - index.html
  - src/
  - dist/
  - node_modules/
  - package.json
  - ...
  - Gruntfile.js
  - VagrantFile
  - bashfile.sh (runs via config.vm.provision)

I'd like to move all of my vagrant and build scripts to their own directory so I can keep the home directory a bit less cluttered.  The goal is to have the following:

- Home

  - index.html
  - src/
  - dist/
  - node_modules/
  - package.json
  - ...
  - deploy/
  - Gruntfile.js
  - Vagrantfile
  - bashfile.sh

How can I make this happen as far as the vagrant install goes?  When I try to `vagrant up` from `deploy/` I run into not being able to run `npm install` as the shell script cannot find package.json, and the server also ends up installating in there, so it thinks `deploy/` is the home directory.

This is just my own idea.  Perhaps it's pointless and useless in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you need to add a shared folder for your parent `Home` folder. It works with absolute path.

Lets say your Home directory is under `/Users/<user>/project/Home` you will add in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/<user>/project/Home", "/project"
```

then from the VM, you can do `cd /project` and run `npm install` from there

Comment: relative path project host is not authorize ?